# Awk code to select multiple patterns

Tags: linux, shell, awk

This is my input file, say modified.txt

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4544 | n479826 | 2012-08-28 07:12:33 -0400 (Tue, 28 Aug 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml

CET-402: some text comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 -0400 (Tue, 04 Sep 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/base.cfg
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/prod.cfg
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/qa.cfg
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/uat.cfg

CET-438: some text comment
```

My output should be like:

```
r4544 | n479826 | 2012-08-28 07:12:33 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/base.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/prod.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/qa.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/uat.cfg
```

the input file is a sample svn-log file. I want to filter all modified (M) files with their respective credentials.
Can someone help with some sample code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F"|" '/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}/^   M/{gsub(/   M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> awk -F"|" '/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}/^   M/{gsub(/   M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}' temp
r4544 | n479826 | 2012-08-28 07:12:33| /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29| /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29| /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/base.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29| /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/prod.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29| /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/qa.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29| /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/uat.cfg
```

explanation:

```
/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}
```

The above block of code will execute only when the line starts with a letter r.
inside the block says store the first field in a ,second field in b and third field from input is :

```
2012-08-28 07:12:33 -0400 (Tue, 28 Aug 2012)
```

but i need only the date with timestamp and the rest is obsolete for me.
it is always 20 characters.
so i took a substring from the third field and stored it in c.

my main interest was the line which starts with /^   M/ which i have to display with the information present in the previous line which start with r
and for sure there is a line which starts with r before our desired line which has all the information i have to prepend the lines which start with M.

so every time a line starts with M will be prepended with the values stored in a b and c.

```
M/{gsub(/ M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}
```

gsub part will remove the part of "   M " with a space from the current line.
print part just prepends the value of a b and c to the current line with | as teh separator.