# Need to understand this awk statement

Tags: linux, awk

I was reading this question
[Awk code to select multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336710/awk-code-to-select-multiple-patterns)

The user has this as input

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4544 | n479826 | 2012-08-28 07:12:33 -0400 (Tue, 28 Aug 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml

CET-402: some text comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 -0400 (Tue, 04 Sep 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/base.cfg
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/prod.cfg
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/qa.cfg
   M /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/uat.cfg

CET-438: some text comment
```

and he wants this as output

```
r4544 | n479826 | 2012-08-28 07:12:33 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/RTSConfig.xml
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/base.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/prod.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/qa.cfg
r4550 | n479826 | 2012-09-04 05:51:29 | /branches/8.6.0/conf/src/main/config/uat.cfg
```

The correct answer is this

```
awk -F"|" '/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}/^   M/{gsub(/   M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}' your_file
```

I didn't understood that fully.

Now i got this part

`/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}/^`

but i didn't get the second part
`M/{gsub(/   M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}`

My problems are

1. What is `M` means in the beginning
   2.Now awk will read the file line by line so it means at the second line
   i.e Chngaed paths the value of `a =0` because there is no field separator `|` on that line
2. Now when the awk comes to third line
   then again `a,b,c =0` and `$0 = /bracnhes` but how is the result still showing the old value of a,b,c

I am getting confused when awk is used on multi lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was lazy enough to explain the answer :)
But lemme put my lazyness aside for some time now:

```
/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}
```

The above block of code will execute only when the line starts with a letter r.
inside the block says store the first field in a ,second field in b and third field from input is :

```
2012-08-28 07:12:33 -0400 (Tue, 28 Aug 2012)
```

but i need only the date with timestamp and the rest is obsolete for me.
it is always 20 characters.
so i took a substring from the third field and stored it in c.

my main interest was the line which starts with /^   M/ which i have to display with the information present in the previous line which start with r
and for sure there is a line which starts with r before our desired line which has all the information i have to prepend the lines which start with M.

so every time a line starts with M will be prepended with the values stored in a b and c.

```
M/{gsub(/ M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}
```

gsub part will remove the part of "   M " with a space from the current line.
print part just prepends the value of a b and c to the current line with | as teh separator.

This what the logic is!

I will be back into my lazy mode now :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

`/^r/{a=$1;b=$2;c=substr($3,0,20)}`

1. It matches for the only lines starting with `r` and some digits. so it gets a,b,c variables

`/^   M/{gsub(/   M /," ");print a"|"b"|"c"|"$0}`

1. This matches for the line strating with `spaces and M` to get the other part. During this matching, The a,b,c will be fteched form the previous saved value

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that values of a, b and c are not replaced before the M is encountered. so it is still appended to the print statement.